# Can't connect to local Homebrew MySQL instance with Wordpress wp-config

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to connect to my local MySQL database with the wp-config file of a Wordpress install i'm mirroring.

I have apache running from my /Sites folder on my Mac and currently have the site on /localhost/site.

I've used Homebrew to install MySQL on my MacOS 10.7 Lion.

I have the correct user name and password and selected database, but am getting the "Error establishing a database connection" error.

Any help or direction to where I can find an answer would be appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Did you start the MySQL server? Do you see it running (in Activity Monitor or `ps`)?

Comment: Thank you for responding. It was running, but I think there may have been some other issues involved. I decided to use MAMP instead. Thank you for your input, however.